# Copy one file to another folder with same filename with xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, xp-cmdshell

I have one csv file (pipe separated).**I want to remove very first line of that CSV and at the same time,I have to move same file with same filename into another folder**.
After that,I have to insert that CSV into SQL table.I know,I have to use "Bulk Insert" for this.But,Main difficulty I am facing,to move that file with same **filename**(as I mentioned above).

After that,this process will continue on daily basis.So that,I've to take care that,File which I will gonna be insert into table,is must be fresh(latest file I've to pick up).So, can anyone help me out in these 2 scenarios?

Technology : I am using as SQL and xp_cmdshell.

````
Exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
reconfigure
exec xp_cmdshell 'robocopy *.txt C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\abc C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\pqr /XF *att*.txt'
exec xp_cmdshell 'copy C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\abc C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\ProcessedData'
exec xp_cmdshell 'del C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\abc\*.txt'


exec xp_cmdshell 'more +1 C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\pqr\*.txt>C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\To_be_processed\*.txt'




bulk insert test_21012019
from 'C:\Users\ngavhane\Desktop\To_be_processed\'
with
(

fieldterminator='|',
rowterminator='\n'
);
Print 'File data has been inserted into table' ```
````

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/79-loading-all-files-from-directory-to-table

Comment: thank Nicola.But,It is not working for my request..